# Run a terminal command and saving the values returned using Python/Django?

Tags: python, linux, django, command-line

I have a question regarding the use of Python.

How do i run a command line command using Python? And after running the command, 
how do i save the returned values?

For example:

```
user@home:~$: ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 ..[etc] home
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 357 ..[etc] examples.doc
```

So what i intend to do, is to run the command ls -l and than save the response into a database using Python.

I intend to implement the above example in Django.

May I know if it is possible? What kind of commands I cannot execute?

How do i implement it?

Any links, tutorials, advice is more than welcome!

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use subprocess -- http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html and http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
stdout, stderr = Popen(['echo', 'Hello World!'], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
print stdout.split('\n')
```

Comment: looks great. how would i store the result into a database?

Comment: To store in a database, go through the django tutorial: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 2):

reece's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383148/run-a-terminal-command-and-saving-the-values-returned-using-python-django/3383171#3383171) almost works, but you need to append Popen with .communicate()

so it would be:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
stdout, stderr = Popen(['echo', 'Hello World!'], shell=False, stdout=PIPE).communicate()
```

Or in Python 2.7 you can use:

```
from subprocess import check_output
stdout = check_output(['echo', 'Hello World!'], shell=False)
```

See subprocess: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually asking the right question here. As others have said, `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen` are the answers to the question 'how can I run a shell command in Python.

But that's not the question you are *really* asking. What you actually want to know is, how can I get the files in a directory? And the answer to that question is to use `os.listdir()`. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the standard subprocess model - it has an example for doing just that:

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline